# Check for how long is a table locked (in seconds)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

I'm creating a new version of a Stored Procedure which uses a Transaction in the whole Stored Procedure to update and insert data in 3 tables. The tables gets locked while doing this.

In the new version, i'll work on #temp tables and apply a transaction only in the end where i insert and update the final tables to minimize the locking time.

**How can i check for how long is a table locked?.**

So i can compare both Stored Procedures and say if is there an improvement on the table lock time.

Comment: I think you could improve your question by clarifying if your original procedure actually really acquire a "Table Lock" (locking the whole table) or if it lock some records of the table which generate in most of the case a lesser lock like "Page lock".

Comment: You can view locks at sys.dm_tran_locks. I would recommend reading http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/write-your-own-sp-lock-system-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2005/ and applying it to your needs.